# Java Regular Expression Concatenate single letters

Tags: java, regex

I suspect I need a look around of some sort to achieve the replacement that I want.

In simple terms, I want to combine all single alphanumeric into one term.  The single letters could be at the start or in the middle of a sentence.

- A A Towing becomes AA Towing (Combine A + A)
- PL B C J Enterprises becomes PL BCJ Enterprises (Combine B+C+J)
- A B CD E Limitation becomes AB CD E Limitation (Combine A+B)
- About A River becomes About A River (No changes)

Comment: What have you tried? When you put it to paper, what logic to solve the problem do you get?

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: It is remarkable that all examples use single upper case letters. Would you expect "When a B C event" to become "When aBC event"? If not, omit the lower case a-z from anubhava's answer. (Specs must be spic and span ;-) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String str = "PL B C J";
String repl = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\b[A-Za-z]\\b) +(?=\\b[A-Za-z]\\b)", "");
//=> PL BCJ
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bY7iV2/1)

**Explanation:** This regex will match 1 or more space only if it is followed by a single letter and preceded by a single letter and replaces that matched space(s) with an empty string.